# How do you replace certain lines in a text file?

Tags: python, file, replace

I'm creating a password generator, and I have a file with all the saved passwords, i want to rewrite certain lines of the code. Here is my code

```
reason = input("Why would you like to use this password?\n")
file = open("Password Saver.rtf", "a+")
file = open("Password Saver.rtf", "r+")
occ = 0

for line in file:
    line = line.casefold()
    words = line.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        if word == reason.casefold():
            occ +=  1
        else:
            continue
if occ > 1 or occ == 1:
    Duplicate = input("You have already made a password with that reason, would you like to write it again?\n")
```

After this I want it to rewrite some specific lines. Is this possible?

Comment: You could always store the entire text in a variable, change the text in the variable and then write it to the file

Comment: Why have you opened the same file twice?

Comment: FYI, `occ > 1 or occ == 1` can be simplified to `occ >= 1`

Comment: There's no need for `else: continue`. Loops automatically continue unless you break out of them. And `if` statements don't have to have an `else:` if it doesn't do anything. OTOH, you probably should break out of the loop as soon as you find a match. Or you could just use `if reason.casefold() in words:`

Comment: I've opened the same file twice because if the file isn't yet created, I have to create it.

Comment: You should use `line.strip()` to remove the newline. Or use `line.split()` to split on any whitespace, not just a single space.

Comment: You're checking for the reason as any word in the line of the file. So if the password matches the reason, you'll rewrite it. You should probably use a more specific way of comparing. Or maybe you should be using a database.

Comment: I want to rewrite a chunk of code and replace it with a different chunk, not just a single line.

Answer (score 0):

use `configparser`,
that will be easy to read  and changes variable

https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

it's taken from the [quick start config parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start)

```py
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['DEFAULT'] = {'ServerAliveInterval': '45',
                     'Compression': 'yes',
                     'CompressionLevel': '9'}
config['bitbucket.org'] = {}
config['bitbucket.org']['User'] = 'hg'
config['topsecret.server.com'] = {}
topsecret = config['topsecret.server.com']
topsecret['Port'] = '50022'     # mutates the parser
topsecret['ForwardX11'] = 'no'  # same here
config['DEFAULT']['ForwardX11'] = 'yes'
with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
  config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace a line that starts with a keyword provided, hope it helps. Don't think there's a way to do it without reading the entire file.

```
file = 'pathtofile'
myKeyword = "Test3"
myNewLine = "The New line i want Test3 to be replaced with\n"
with open(file, "r+") as f:
    allLines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in allLines:
        if not line.startswith(myKeyword):
            f.write(line)
        else:
            f.write(myNewLine)
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work, sorry for the long wait. I was wondering if there was more you could evaluate on?

Comment: how does it not work ?